# NullPointerException when putting an EditText in XML Layout File

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

This is an Android Development related question.
I make use of the ADT and Eclipse Indigo in a Windows 7 64bits

First we have the xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
  </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Second, we have the class that makes a reference to the xml file right above

```
package com.example.test_table;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Home extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    }

}
```

In third place, we got the declaration in the manifest of the class Home

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.test_table.Home"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

And then, when I try to run, Eclipse returns a nullpointerexception.
But when I remove the EditText from the xml layout file, the application works.
This problem suddenly appeared in my computer and I'm trying to do something about it.

LogCat:

```
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {com.example.test_table/com.example.test_table.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager.updateData(ClipboardExManager.java:241)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.widget.EditText.onFocusChanged(EditText.java:134)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:3727)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5420)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5370)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5348)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseRequestFocus(LayoutInflater.java:753)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at com.example.test_table.Home.onCreate(Home.java:11)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    ... 11 more
```

So, I'd like to know what causes the ADT to stop recognizing an Edittext?

Comment: I would try cleaning your project and re-build. Your code is correct.  Also, post the LogCat if you can.

Comment: I tryed, but it still the same. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This line: `02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager.updateData(ClipboardExManager.java:241)` is curious.  Are you by chance testing on a Samsung device or are you using an emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is strange to me is this log:

```
02-27 22:42:39.051: E/AndroidRuntime(12164):    at android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager.updateData(ClipboardExManager.java:241)
```

Putting that into a Google search seems to pull results about a bug in Samsung devices and the soft keyboard.  I am assuming that is what you are using because it does not look like any non-Samsung results are appearing.  I would look into this bug, and possibly try to disable the keyboard from appearing when the application is first launched.  This may stop it from crashing in `onCreate()` until you actually focus the `EditText` by clicking it.  Putting Something like this in `onCreate()` can help you out with that:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Like I said in my comment, your code is correct.  Try testing it on the emulator or another Android device.  I will try to help you further if anything else comes up.

Here are some of the links I skimmed through:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35358
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1655619
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36322

Comment: Thaks a lot for the help. You are really good in answering questions. In fact, it was my Samsung device's fault.

Answer (score 0):

try using edit text in your java file and refer it

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(path);
```